# How to set point size and line thickness in visualization module using Open3d？

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d

I refer the code in http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/visualization/visualization.html#Function-draw_geometries and the code as follows:

```
import open3d as o3d

print("Let's draw a box using o3d.geometry.LineSet.")
points = [
[0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1],
]
lines = [
[0, 1],
[0, 2],
[1, 3],
[2, 3],
[4, 5],
[4, 6],
[5, 7],
[6, 7],
[0, 4],
[1, 5],
[2, 6],
[3, 7],
]
colors = [[1, 0, 0] for i in range(len(lines))]
line_set = o3d.geometry.LineSet(
points=o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points),
lines=o3d.utility.Vector2iVector(lines),
)
line_set.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)
point_cloud2 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
point_cloud2.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
point_cloud2.paint_uniform_color([0, 1, 0])

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([line_set, point_cloud2])
```

I can get the lines and points:
[image]
How could I set the plotted point sizes and line thicknesses?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this via `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries`. `draw_geometries` is just a helper method provided to easily use `o3d.visualization.Visualizer` class.

In `o3d.visualization.Visualizer`, you can increase both point size and line width by updating render options:-

```
# Replace last line of o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([line_set, point_cloud2]) with below code.
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window()
vis.add_geometry(line_set)
vis.add_geometry(point_cloud2)
vis.get_render_option().line_width = 5
vis.get_render_option().point_size = 20
vis.run()
```

[image]

See here ([Open3d source code](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/blob/master/cpp/open3d/visualization/visualizer/RenderOption.h#L51)) for the min/max limits for both line width and point size.

Comment: This works with latest development package, not with v0.17.0 - https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/pull/6116. Download from http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/getting_started.html#development-version-pip